# Assign/run macro code from a button without the need for a separate macro in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro that creates two buttons on each worksheet in a workbook. Each button runs a sort macro that sorts a specific range in each worksheet. All macros are stored in PERSONAL.XLSB (see below).

This works fine, however, if I want to share this workbook with others, I have to export the 2 sort macros (i. e. `Module32.btnF` and `Module3.btnTD`), and the user has to import the two macros into their PERSONAL.XLSB. This works but is obviously not ideal.

I'd like the macro to create the sort buttons but run the sort code without the need for two individual sort macros.

I have created two separate variables that contain the macro code for each sort but these will not/does not run from the `.OnAction` statement.

I've found some information around `VBProject.VBComponents` but have been unable to figure out how to make this work for my requirements.

```
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Item("ws").CodeModule.AddFromString(strCode)
```

Note: `ws` - current worksheet, variable `strCode` - with sort code.

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub AddSortButtons1Point2()

    '
    '   Macro: AddSortButtons1Point2
    ' Purpose: Used to add sort button to each worksheet in the workbook.
    '
    '          1 - Sort Race Details by Field Order
    '          2 - Sort Race Details by TD Rating
    '

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim btn1 As Button
    Dim btn2 As Button
    Dim NextFree As Integer
    Dim TwoDown As Integer
    Dim NextFreeF As Integer
    Dim NextFreeTD As Integer
    Dim t1 As Range
    Dim t2 As Range

    For Each ws In Sheets ' Select all worksheets in workbook.
        ws.Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
        NextFree = Range("F7:F" & _
        Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
        TwoDown = NextFree + 2
        Set t1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(TwoDown, 6), Cells(TwoDown, 6))
        Set btn1 = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t1.Left, t1.Top, t1.Width, t1.Height)
        With btn1
            .Placement = xlMove
            .OnAction = "btnF"
            .Caption = "Sort By Field Order"
            .Name = "Sort By Field Order"
        End With
        t1.Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Set t2 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(TwoDown, 10), Cells(TwoDown, 10))
        Set btn2 = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t2.Left, t2.Top, t2.Width, t2.Height)
        With btn2
           .Placement = xlMove
           .OnAction = "btnTD"
           .Caption = "Sort By TD Rating"
           .Name = "Sort By TD Rating"
        End With
        t2.Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        ' Code added to protect the buttons.
        ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=False, Scenarios:=False, _
            AllowFormattingCells:=False, AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
            AllowFormattingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
            AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
            AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
            AllowDeletingRows:=False, AllowSorting:=False, AllowFiltering:=False, _
            AllowUsingPivotTables:=False
    Next ws

End Sub

Sub btnF()

    '
    '   Macro: btnF (aka Module32.btnF)
    ' Purpose: Sort race details in field order (horse number).
    '

    NextFreeF = Range("B7:B" & _
        Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
    NextFreeF = NextFreeF - 1
    Range("B" & NextFreeF).Select
    Range("A7:P" & NextFreeF).Select
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B7:B" & NextFreeF), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A7:P" & NextFreeF)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub

Sub btnTD()

    '
    '   Macro: btnTD (aka Module3.btnTD)
    ' Purpose: Sort race details by TD Rating.
    '

    NextFreeTD = Range("B7:O" & _
        Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
    NextFreeTD = NextFreeTD - 1
    Range("B" & NextFreeTD).Select
    Range("A7:P" & NextFreeTD).Select
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("O7:O" & NextFreeTD), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "AAA,AA,A,BBB,BB,B,CCC,CC,C,DDD,DD,D", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A7:P" & NextFreeTD)
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I'm currently at a standstill. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.OnAction "MySub"` with `Sub MySub()` located in a standard module works fine for me.

Comment: Hi @omegastripes Thanks for your reply. You are correct. This works in the code I have included. What I want to do though is NOT have Sub MySub(). What I want is to define the Sub code in a variable (or something else), read the code in the "main" macro (AddSortButtons1Point2) when creating the buttons, then the buttons use that code when clicked. This will eliminate the need to pass on any macros when sharing the workbook. Currently, users have the worksheets with the buttons included, however, they don't have the 2 Subs (btnF & btnTD) unless they import them into their Personal.xlsb file.

Comment: Why does it need to go to the personal.xlsb file and not just redistribute the  workbook with the buttons with the code included?

Comment: Hi @jamheadart It doesn't need to go to Personal.xlsb. In fact, I don't want it to go to Personal.xlsb. The macros that I run to create the workbook are stored in my Personal.xlsb, including AddSortButtons1Point2 (which creates the buttons). The distributed workbook won't include the AddSortButtons1Point2 but when I distribute the workbook, the buttons are looking for btnF & btnTD in the users Personal.xlsb. How do I include ONLY the (sort) code for the buttons in the workbook when I run the AddSortButtons1Point2 macro?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to host the macros on a hidden worksheet in a workbook. When you "copy" that worksheet, it'll copy the macros too. You can then include this in the new workbook you've created and get the buttons to look for the macros on the worksheet.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll have a think about that one & get back to you. Thanks @jamheadart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I get it.
So maybe a good solution is to copy the sorting macros from PERSONAL.XLSB when adding the buttons.

[EDIT] 
Try adding **btnF()** and **btnTD()** to a new module in PERSONAL.XLSB (lets call it "SortMacros") and then then try the following.

```
Sub AddSortButtons1Point2()

    '
    '   Macro: AddSortButtons1Point2
    ' Purpose: Used to add sort button to each worksheet in the workbook.
    '
    '          1 - Sort Race Details by Field Order
    '          2 - Sort Race Details by TD Rating
    '

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim btn1 As Button
    Dim btn2 As Button
    Dim NextFree As Integer
    Dim TwoDown As Integer
    Dim NextFreeF As Integer
    Dim NextFreeTD As Integer
    Dim t1 As Range
    Dim t2 As Range

    For Each ws In Sheets ' Select all worksheets in workbook.
        ws.Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
        NextFree = Range("F7:F" & _
        Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
        TwoDown = NextFree + 2
        Set t1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(TwoDown, 6), Cells(TwoDown, 6))
        Set btn1 = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t1.Left, t1.Top, t1.Width, t1.Height)
        With btn1
            .Placement = xlMove
            .OnAction = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!btnF"
            .Caption = "Sort By Field Order"
            .Name = "Sort By Field Order"
        End With
        t1.Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Set t2 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(TwoDown, 10), Cells(TwoDown, 10))
        Set btn2 = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t2.Left, t2.Top, t2.Width, t2.Height)
        With btn2
           .Placement = xlMove
           .OnAction = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!btnTD"
           .Caption = "Sort By TD Rating"
           .Name = "Sort By TD Rating"
        End With
        t2.Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        ' Code added to protect the buttons.
        ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=False, Scenarios:=False, _
            AllowFormattingCells:=False, AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
            AllowFormattingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
            AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
            AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
            AllowDeletingRows:=False, AllowSorting:=False, AllowFiltering:=False, _
            AllowUsingPivotTables:=False
    Next ws

End Sub

Sub CopySortMacros()
        On Error GoTo endsub
        Dim sortMacrosModule As Object, destModule As Object

        Set sortMacrosModule = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").VBProject.VBComponents("SortMacros").CodeModule
        Set destModule = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule).CodeModule

        destModule.Name = sortMacrosModule.Name
        destModule.AddFromString sortMacrosModule.Lines(1, sortMacrosModule.CountOfLines)

Exit Sub

endsub:
          With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
              .Remove .Item(destModule.Name)
          End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok Nic. I think we're onto something here. So I created a module called "SortMacros" which contains both btnF() and btnTD(). I've copied & added CopySortMacros() to the end of AddSortButtons1Point2(). Can you please be more explicit as to how & where in AddSortButtons1Point2() I "call" CopySortMacros()?

Comment: I just want to confirm that you added CopySortMacros() **after** AddSortButtons1Point2() and not in it? Then in AddsortButtons1Point2() you can just type "CopySortMacros" before the for loop.

Comment: Correct. CopySortMacros() was added AFTER AddSortButtons1Point2() & the CopySortMacros call was added just before the "For Each ws In Sheets" loop. As such, I'm now receiving "Ambiguous name detected:" for both btnF & btnTD when the buttons are clicked. If I add SortMacros to the .OnAction statement (i.e. .OnAction = "SortMacros.btnF"), the button sorts work, however, that defeats the purpose as this will not work on another computer that doesn't have SortMacros, btnF, btnTD, etc. Also, when I try to save the workbook, Excel now asks me to save it as a Macro-Enabled File Type. Thoughts?

Comment: Ok. I've edited the code above. The macro's will only copy over one time now, and not make duplicate modules on every run (which was causing the ambiguity), and the buttons' .OnAction now explicitly refers to the copied macros. You'll have to save it as an xlsm file, yes.

Comment: Hi Nic, Sorry for the delay in responding. I've been in transit the past couple of days. Great work! This worked like a charm... once I added CopySortMacros before the For Loop ;-) Thank you very, very much for all your help! If you're ever in Sydney, Australia, look me up. I owe you a few beers. All the best! Billy J.

Comment: Haha, no problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a module in your workbook instead and just move the code from PERSONAL.XLSB to there.

Comment: Hi Nic, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see my reply to @jamheadart